# SonarQube without web server and specific metrics

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am trying create application that uses sonar to analyze my source code.

I need to be able to create as much analyzers I need to analyze only specific metrics, if possible, not all of them.

Since I don't need sonar web server (or database), is it possible to run analyzers without it? What is the purpose of web server if analyzer does the job?

Ideally I want to write a method that accepts array of metrics that need to be analyzed, and to get appropriate response in shortest time possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of web server is to store and present the data. You can do historical comparisons and trace the software state in time.

Q: Is it possible to run analyzers without web server?

That depend how it was written, you might want to dig into the source code and extract the library that is responsible for the analyze part.

Comment: Yes but I dont need storing and presenting the data, I just need to get result for metrics I want in one call. Without digging into sonar code, I was wondering is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a programmatical way to extract the analyzer result data, you can try using the [RESTful API](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API). This will allow you to retrieve issues that match a specific rule, for example, which I *think* is what you mean by "analyze only specific metrics".

You should also bear in mind that most of the metrics and rules that SonarQube presents are from other tools... SonarQube bundles them all in one handy spot, but you can still run [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/), and [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) separately... the other major component SonarQube offers is code metrics (complexity, LOC, etc) which you can find in a number of other libraries but I do not know specifically which one SonarQube uses.

Comment: RESTful API means that I have server online, which is what I want to avoid. My metrics I mean that I need to analyze certain aspects of code and get results, but SonarQube (by my understanding) analyzes all of them (waist of computation) and exposes results via RESTful API.